# Remove ignoring response message from Scrapy log

Tags: python, scrapy

I use python scrapy and website has a lot of incorrect links, leading to 404 status code pages. Scrapy add message to log "ignoring response 404" - it fills in log very much, how to remove that kind of message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrapy uses python's `logging` module, so you can just do it the usual way - get the relevant logger and change its logging level.

The documentation even shows this exact example under [Logging - Advanced customization](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html#advanced-customization):

```
import logging
import scrapy


class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    # ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        logger = logging.getLogger('scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror')
        logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```